# ImportError: cannot import name 'HeNormal' from 'keras.initializers'

Tags: python, keras, gpu, initializer

If I try to run the line

```
from keras.initializers import HeNormal
```

I get the error message

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'HeNormal' from 'keras.initializers'
```

I'm in a conda environment where I installed keras-gpu with

```
conda install -c anaconda keras-gpu
```

and from

```
import keras
keras.__version__
```

I get

```
'2.3.1'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You can use Keras from the TensorFlow package, like `from tensorflow.keras.initializers import HeNormal`.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal I tried this but it didn't solve, by the way I solved in the way I wrote below. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by replacing HeNormal with he_normal, since in initializers.py it was defined in this way.

I don't know why since in all the other devices I can import it with HeNormal